# Why is the tag [layouts] replaced with [layout] instead of the other way around?

Tags: discussion, tags, plurals

Is there any particular reason it was changed to be non plural instead of plural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a tag synonym pair is suggested, the system automatically makes the more frequently used tag the "master" and the less common one the "link." Users can only vote on whether two tags are synonymous, not which one should be kept as the "real" tag.

Comment: If people use the link enough and then it becomes more commonly used will it then become master?

Comment: @George, no, once the synonym is created, no more instances of the link are ever created; the system automatically converts to the master.